# New FMDB not encrypting using SqlCipher?

Tags: swift, encryption, sqlite, fmdb

I've added [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) and FMDB/SQLCipher to my cocoa app in swift. I found some of the links which were telling how to export existing unencrypted sqlite3 database to encrypted one. But I want to create new encrypted database. So I followed the code like below, but database is not encrypting, still it can be open by 3rd party tool such as sql lite browser. Please help me.

```
 private let key = "password"  
 let databaseFileName = "sample.db"
 var pathToDatabase: String!
 var database: FMDatabase!

 let documentsDirectory = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString) as String
 pathToDatabase = documentsDirectory.appending("/\(databaseFileName)")

 if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathToDatabase) {
      database = FMDatabase(path: pathToDatabase!)
      if database != nil {
            // Open the database.
            if database.open() {
                database.setKey(key)
            }
            else {
                print("Could not open the database.")
            }
        }
    }
```

I checked `database.setKey(key)` returns false, what could be the problem?